# Ogg playback in Java

Tags: java, oggvorbis

I have tried many times trying to get ogg support in Java but have been unsuccessful.

I have tried using Jorbis and another method for implementing ogg playback in Java but cannot seem to do so.

Can someone point me in the right direction on implementing ogg in java?

Answer (score 1):

3D sound system is the best I've tried(It just works) and can be used not just in JPCT: http://www.jpct.net/forum2/index.php/topic,1057.0.html

Comment: After testing the library; it uses over 160MB to play a 4MB ogg file. Anything else?

Comment: Never had such problems. There are 2 ogg plugins for the library, did you try the other? Also I suggest reporting that bug.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [FFsampledSP](http://www.tagtraum.com/ffsampledsp/index.html). It's a free, FFmpeg-based implementation for Win and OSX that implements the `javax.sound.sampled` interfaces.